# kubernetes getting error "Container image mongo:3.4.20 already present on machine"

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

Back-off restarting the failed container, the description is Container image `mongo:3.4.20` already present on the machine

I have removed all container into that system name mongo, removed all POD, svc, deployment, and rc, but getting the same error, also I tried to label another node with a different name and used that label in `yaml` but I got the same error.

I used below `yaml` for creating Deployment, in this case, I used to map system with name `app=mongodb`, also attached one 8 GB disk in AWS as `persistentVolumeClaim`.

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: mongo-deployment
    labels:
      app: mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mongo:3.4.20
        name: mongo
        ports:
        - name: mongo
          containerPort: 27017
          hostPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/data/db"
          name: db-storage
      volumes:
        - name: db-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: db-storage
```

why its always going failed and saying Container image already present on the machine, any cache?

Comment: Are you sure that's the full status and not just one event? Does it appear to be starting and then immediately crashing?

Comment: It looks like the problem is not with image, but with container itself. Generally it help to view logs of failed container "kubectl logs -p POD_NAME".

Comment: @coderanger, yes.. its immediately went to down ,

Comment: @VasilyAngapov `[initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=mongo-deployment-5-94v
 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (2) [8][40], file:WiredTiger.wt, connection: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: No such file or directory
 I -        [initandlisten] Assertion: 28595:2: No such file or directory src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 277
 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 28595 2: No such file or directory, terminating
 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
`

Comment: I have changed mount path from "/data/db" to "/data"  then after its started correctly , anyway not getting error but the massage still getting "Container image "mongo:3.4.20" already present on machine", - may be the container still running in same node

Comment: That is simply information message saying that docker image "mongo:3.4.20 "already present on machine, no need to pull again. You can ignore it.

Answer (score 8):

Addressed in comments, "already present on the machine" is not an error message. That's a pod event and is there only for debugging and tracing to give you an idea of what steps the kubelet is taking during the pod setup process.